# SQL transaction will not work

Tags: mysql

Im trying to run this, but i get an error on line 4 where the transaction starts

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE Testproc1(pi_klassekode CHAR(3)
                          ,pi_klassenavn VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
  START TRANSACTION;
  INSERT INTO klasse 
  VALUES(pi_klassekode,pi_klassenavn);
  COMMIT;
END$$
```

Comment: Could you write down the error? Could you define the table `klasse`? Is it possible that you are missing values?

Comment: Which error exactly?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: [Edit] it into your post, and next time, don't post about an error without also quoting it in full.

Comment: ye kinda had a brain fart not posting it, i realised my mistake when i read the comment

Answer (score 0):

Can you change delimiter and check if it works ?

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE Testproc1(pi_klassekode CHAR(3) ,
    pi_klassenavn VARCHAR(30))//
BEGIN
  START TRANSACTION//
  INSERT INTO klasse VALUES(pi_klassekode,pi_klassenavn)//
  COMMIT//
END//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: tried this, got just more of the nasty red

Error
There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem.


ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 11
STR: //
SQL: delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE Testproc1(pi_klassekode CHAR(3) , 
pi_klassenavn VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
  START TRANSACTION;//

Comment: can you check without `;` semi-colon

Comment: just loads, nothing is happening